# Prove $\mathbb{Z}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ only using interior points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to show that every open ball centered around any integer $\mathbb{Z}$ will contain a real number that's not in $\mathbb{Z}$. How can I show this without using any special theorems like the Archimedean property, etc.?

Comment: One thought for your proof, is that for any $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ there is an interval $(z,z+1)$ which has no integers in it.  Must a ball around $z$ intersect this interval?

Comment: What are your axioms for $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

If $r<2$, then $n+\frac{r}2$ is a non-integer in $B(n,r)$, since the distance between consecutive integers is $1$. This establishes that every $n\in \mathbb Z$ is on the boundary, since every neighborhood of an $n$ contains points not in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Since our definition of open is that all elements of the set are interior points, I want to show at least one point in $\mathbb{Z}$ is not an interior point. But that basically means I need to show that for an integer $z$ there is no radius $r$ such that $(x - r, x + r) \subset \mathbb{Z}$, which means I need to find some real number not an integer in that arbitrary open ball, right?

Comment: @user130018 Ah, whoops, I misread your question. Yes, you're correct; the existence of a point not in the interior implies $\mathbb Z$ is not open, and showing that all such balls are not contained in $\mathbb Z$ for some integer $x$ suffices to show that claim.